# Mazda 3 hatchback 2003 fuel loss of acceleration power

Tags: mazda, mazda-3, power-loss

I was driving to work this morning,making about 100kmp and all of sudden the acceleration drop and could not go more than 80 km/p , no matter how I press the gas pedal,makes only noise but not accelerating power ..
This is the first time it’s happening..
It was driving very fine and recently did a full service 2weeks ago..
Mazda 3 hatchback fuel 
Pls any suggestion will be highly appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Which fuel does the car use?  Any warning lights?  Do you have access to an OBD2 error reader?

Comment: See this and check the answers: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/3053/10976

Comment: Pls It’s fuel, doesn’t show any warning light..
No I don’t have access to that Thanks

Comment: This is problematic, because if it's not throwing any warning lights, then there's a bigger issue with the car. This question is far to vague, and will require too much information in troubleshooting and experience to accurately diagnose and provide any possible solutions. For example, this can be caused by a bad MAFS connection (I had this problem on my Mazda 3), but that causes a check engine light and illuminates other lights as well. If you can't provide any codes or additional information, we're unfortunately not able to provide very much useful assistance without guessing.